# Equation program - Error seems to point to the wrong line

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an app where a user enters between 7-10 numerical values across a few activities. Entries are then used in a fairly layered equation which returns a result to the user. Two values are giving me trouble and producing a `NumberFormatException` that I cannot figure out.

One entry, `IHCValue` is chosen from a spinner as there are only 4 possible choices:

```
<string-array name="ihc_choices">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>
```

This choice is not only used in the equation but determines if additional information is needed.

**Obtaining IHCValue:**

```
   private void directSpinner(){

        int spinnerPosition = scoreSelect.getSelectedItemPosition();
        String[] IHC_Values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ihc_choices);
        String IHCValue = String.valueOf(IHC_Values[spinnerPosition]);
        SharedPrefManager.write(IHC_VALUE, IHCValue);

        //The string to manage Intent defined separately as the intent did not recognize the value of 'String IHCValue'
        String IHCEntry = scoreSelect.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (IHCEntry.equals("2")){
            //Status equivocal, must collect more information before calculation can be performed.
            Intent next = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FishScoreActivity.class);
            startActivity(next);
        } else { //IHCValue of 0,1,3
            //Status is defined, we have enough info to perform calculation.
            Intent last = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CancerDemographicActivity.class);
            startActivity(last);
        }
    }
```

If the user selects "2" from this dropdown the next activity asks for `FISHEntry`, also used in part of the equation:

**Obtaining FISHEntry:**

```
public boolean validateData(){
    boolean validData = false;

    String FISHEntry = enterFISH.getText().toString();

    if (!FISHEntry.equals("")){
        SharedPrefManager.write(FISH_RATIO, FISHEntry);
        validData = true;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter FISH ratio from your report.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        validData = false;
    }
    return validData;
}
```

Then, the user can press a button and run the equation. If the user selected an `IHCValue` of 0,1, or 3 the `FISHEntry` is not needed and the equation runs fine.

If (and only if) `IHCValue = 2` then an additional calculation must be performed within the Equation class, and crashes the app.

**Steps I performed from within the app:**

1. From the spinner, `IHCValue` of 2 is selected.
2. Prompted to enter FISH score, `FISHEntry = 2.3`
3. Press "Calculate" button:

Then the app crashes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "2.3"
    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
    at com.them.health.Equations.MasterEquation.<clinit> 
(MasterEquation.java:42)
```

"2.3" is my `FISHEntry` while line 42 which declares `IHCValue`:

**MasterEquation.java:42**

```
private static int mIHCValue = Integer.parseInt(SharedPrefManager.read(IHC_VALUE, null));
```

FISHEntry is declared on MasterEquation.java:41:

```
private static double mFISHRatio = Double.valueOf(SharedPrefManager.read(FISH_RATIO, null));
```

To be consistent, all values are saved to SharedPrefs as string and I parse int or double as needed when the equation is performed. Also, I received a String-to-Integer error when saving the `IHCValue` directly as an int.

**Method in MasterEquation.java which uses the variables:**

```
private void calcRatioOne(){

    double innerRatio = mIHCValue/mFISHRatio;

    if (mIHCValue == 0 || mIHCValue == 1){
        mRatioOne = 0.0;

    } else if (mIHCValue == 3){
        mRatioOne = 12.75525;

    } else if (mIHCValue == 2){ //IHC = 2 takes FISHEntry into account.

        if (innerRatio >= 2.2){
            mRatioOne = 12.75525;
        }
        if (innerRatio >= 1.8){
            mRatioOne = 1.46495;

        }
        if (innerRatio < 1.8){
            mRatioOne = 0.0;

        }
    }
}
```

`private double mRatioOne;` is defined at the start.

**I have tried the following:**

1. Write values to SharedPrefs as int/float when the user enters them. *Error converting to double when equation is run.*
2. Created a method specifically to handle the `innerRatio` calculations. *Same problem.*
3. Declare and handle IHCValue as a double/float. *Same problem.*
4. Declared IHCValue as `Integer` instead of `int`. *Same problem.*

**This is only a problem when IHCValue = 2**

I am not opposed to changing the IHC Entry from a spinner to another entry method if that would help, but would like to avoid free text since this is the most important entry in the sequence.

**My SharedPrefManager:**

Key declared:

```
public static final String IHC_VALUE = null;
```

Read & Write Method:

```
public static String read(String key, String defValue){
    return userPrefs.getString(key, defValue);
}

public static void write(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = userPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putString(key, value);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping throgh it with a debugger?

Comment: Although it's pretty easy: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "2.3"` please change

Comment: Could someone please explain the down-vote? This was not as simple as "make it not an int". I spent extensive time debugging and the log was misleading, stating that `"2.3"` was associated with `int mIHCValue` while it was actually the value entered for `double mFISHRatio` and no evidence of why these values were crossed.

Comment: Sure, since it's probably mine - it seems to me you did not invest enough time in figuring out the root cause of your problem, and just dumped code with a "why isn't this working?" kinda question. The debugger is unlikely to lie, and give misguided reasons as to why the program is crashing. You did not seem to step through it and try to figure out why `2.3` does not parse well, and simply blamed it on the gremlins as if the code is guaranteed 100% to work fine, but crashes for unknown reasons. also, a lack of a proper [mcve] is another reason.

Comment: the "evidence of why mFISHRatio and mIHCValue were crossed" lies in the code you posted, or the code you did not post. the debugger would have stepped through them as well. tl;dr - saying "i spent extensive time" was obviously not enough time to figure out why it wasn't working. which simply means "spend more time debugging"

Comment: @Shark I appreciate the reply. At first, I wasn't sure where to begin the question - having no debugging experience didn't help that. I spent all this morning exploring the debugger. WOW! Amazingly helpful and insightful. I can tell this will already reduce the amount of questions I need to ask here and to my friends.

Comment: "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for eternity" == "Tell a man why his app is crashing and you don't do much; teach a man how to use a debugger and watch him grow" :D

Comment: @Shark I'm stealing your quote :)! Just an addition here: Use an IDE for writing code. Always. It makes it so much easier to spot mistakes and develop good, quality code. My personal favorite and a generally popular IDE, is [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). There is a free version, but if you are a student, you are allowed to use the Ultimate version for free. The debugger tool of this IDE is easy to learn and also very good. (What Shark called a debugger before, is actually the compiler of the JVM giving an error message)

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich Thanks! I do everything in Android Studio, but was not-so-blissfully unaware of the debug tool. Absolutely blew my mind - prior to that I had an activity who's purpose was to assign my variables to an EditText to make sure they were correct, a very Rube Goldberg approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is obvious from the error message what the problem is. You are trying to assign the value "2.3" to an *integer-type* variable.

> The best solution would be to use a debugger tool, offered within most
>   Integrated Development Environments (IDEs) like [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) or
>   [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/ide/). With that debugger tool, discover why the wrong value is
>   assigned to `IHCValue` in the first place, and act accordingly to fix
>   the fault.

I don't agree with the fix proposed in the comments by @shark; assigning a `Float` to an `int` is an incompatible operation. My suggestion is to change the type of *mIHCValue* to `double`.

If *mIHCValue* has to be an integer, then convert it from a String, to a double and then cast as an integer. Like so:

```
private double originalIHC = Double.valueOf(SharedPrefManager.read(IHC_VALUE, null));
private static int mIHCValue = (int) originalIHC;
```

Let me explain why I did this in 2 lines. Since the value of the String is not an integer, but a floating point number, we have to parse it as a double first. But to convert a String to the primitive `double` is not possible, so we have to use the Wrapper class `Double` for this.

The Wrapper class `Double` (boxing) is not compatible with a primitive type other than `double`, so we assign the "wrapped" value to its primitive first.

After converting the initial value to a double primitive, we can cast it to an integer like I  displayed.

**Note** that this solution will help you get only the integer part of any floating point number. For example, if the *`mIHCValue`* is `2.8` or `2.0012` or `2.532` or `2.9999999`, the resulting integer will always be **`2`**. So, be careful and think about what it is that you want to achieve.

Hope this helps.

Comment: or prevent entering `"2.3"` if it needs to be an integer; the solution really depends on the project requirement.

but i agree; your solution is better :)

Comment: @shark Yes, exactly! But just for the record, this solution isn't just better; the operation you suggested in the comments will not even compile. You can't assign a `Float` to an `int`.

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich I will try this now, however `"2.3"` is entered for the FISH value (which is a double), not the IHC value (int). The logcat shows that the problem is with IHC value, which can only be an integer value of 0-3.

Comment: @SentientFlesh If it is *"supposed"* to be an int, then the problem might be caused by the `SharedPrefManager.read()` method

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich Okay, can't try your answer at the moment but I've updated the question with the SharedPref methods in case it's something there. Hope this works! Thanks for the quick feedback.

Comment: well, i hope it gets the point across, regardless of whether it compiles or not :)

Comment: @SentientFlesh No problem, that's what StackOverflow is for! The `read()` method doesn't seem to do anything strange. I assume that `userPrefs.getString()` will return either the key or some default.
Try the method I posted and if that doesn't work let me know so we can figure out why IHCValue is not an integer. Also, consider upvoting if you happen to find this helpful

Comment: @SentientFlesh Last piece of advice, try to trace the variable of IHCValue to its origin, to figure out why you get a floating number sometimes. If it should always be an integer, then the solution I have proposed is just a workaround. If it is sometimes an integer, sometimes a floating point, then it is the right solution.

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich This worked to remove the `NumberFormatException`! I cannot upvote, someone downvoted my question and I am now below 15 rep :( but consider it answered! Now that that problem is solved, I can start figuring out why my values are off compared to accepted values.

Comment: @SentientFlesh They probably downvoted because your question is badly formatted and there is too much redundant information that makes it hard to read. Nevertheless, I have fixed your reputation problem ;)